# Update div content in real time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to web design, and I wanted to make a rectangle which says "true" if the user has scrolled, and turn to "false" after one second has passed.

```js
var hasScroll = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    hasScroll = true;
    $("#rectangle").html(hasScroll.toString());
    setTimeout(function() {
      hasScroll = false;
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
body { height: 800px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

However, even though the variable "hasScroll" changes exactly how I want, I can't seem to find a way to make the div show the hasScroll status in real-time.

Comment: You're setting the variable name to false, but never actually setting the .html element with the new variables value. Try adding the `$("rectangle").html(hasScroll.toString());` again in the `setTimeout` function after setting the variable back to false.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set the `#rectangle`'s text again after the scrolling is done. You'll also probably want to set/clear a `setTimeout` that only runs once no scroll events have been triggered for 1000ms:

```js
let scrollingTimeout;
const rectangle = document.querySelector('#rectangle');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (scrollingTimeout) clearTimeout(scrollingTimeout);
  else rectangle.textContent = 'true';
  scrollingTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('setting text to false');
    rectangle.textContent = 'false';
    scrollingTimeout = null;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 800px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectangle">abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, Just put the same line `$("#rectangle").html(hasScroll.toString());` after setting `hasScroll = false;`

For ex.,

```
var hasScroll = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        hasScroll = true;
        $("#rectangle").html(hasScroll.toString());
        setTimeout(function() {
          hasScroll = false;
          $("#rectangle").html(hasScroll.toString()); // To show false
        }, 1000);
      });
    });
```